# TypeError: Cannot read property "values" from undefined. (line 2, file "Code")

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I had a sendEmails function that worked, but now it there is a bug.

I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property "values" from undefined. (line 2, file
>   "Code")

I have a simple form that has 3 columns (including the form timestamp) - Section A and Section B. I added a trigger to run the script when a new line is added to the form. I use the same script for a bunch of other things, but now for some reason it is not working.

```
function sendEmails(formResponse) {
  var answers = formResponse.values;
  var SectionA = answers [1];
  var SectionB = answers [2];

  var html = "<html><strong>Section A: </strong>"+ SectionA + "<html><strong><br />Section B: </strong>" + SectionB;

  var range = formResponse.range;
  var row = range.getRow();
  var column = range.getLastColumn();

  try {
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: 'email@gmail.com',
      subject: SectionA,
    htmlBody: html,
  });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("Did not send email to " + Sponsor + ". See error: " + e);
    range.getSheet().getRange(row, 3).setValue("EMAIL NOT SENT");
    return;
  } 
  range.getSheet().getRange(row, 3).setValue("EMAIL SENT");
}
```

Comment: What is this form? Are you working in Google Sheets, or working with Google Forms? And what kind of object is `FormResponse`?

Comment: The function is running, so the trigger must still be installed.  But, you might try deleting the trigger and installing it again.  The event object will be null if you run the code from the code editor, but if an event is triggering the function to run then it should be passing an event object.  Which makes me think that it could be a bug.

Comment: The question is unclear as it doesn't include enough details and because it's using wrong terms like "simple form that has 3 columns" (forms have questions not columns but it looks that should say "simple sheet" instead of "simple form").